# Loading data into Hive Table from HDFS in Cloudera VM

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When using the Cloudera VM how can you access information in the HDFS? I know there isn't a direct path to the HDFS but I also don't see how to dynamically access it.

After creating a Hive Table through the Hive CLI I attempted to load some data from a file located in the HDFS:

```
load data inpath '/test/student.txt' into table student;
```

But then I just get this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/test/student.txt'': No files matching path hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/test/student.txt
```

I also tried to just load data not in the HDFS into a Hive Table like so:

```
load data inpath '/home/cloudera/Desktop/student.txt' into table student;
```

However that just produced this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/home/cloudera/Desktop/student.txt'': No files matching path hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/Desktop/student.txt
```

Once again I see it trying to access data with the root of `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020` and I'm not sure what that is, but it doesn't seem to be the root directory for the HDFS.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I made sure the file is located in the HDFS so I don't know why this error is coming up or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> how can you access information in the HDFS

Well, you certainly don't need to use Hive to do it. `hdfs dfs` commands are how you interact with HDFS.

> I'm not sure what that is, but it doesn't seem to be the root directory for the HDFS

It is the root of HDFS. `quickstart.cloudera` is the hostname of the VM. Port 8020 is the HDFS port.

---

Your exceptions are from the difference in using the `LOCAL` keyword.

What you're doing

```
LOAD DATA INPATH <hdfs location>
```

VS what you seem to be wanting

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH <local file location>
```

---

Or if the files are in HDFS, it's not clear how you have put files into it, but HDFS definitely doesn't have a /home folder or a Desktop, so the second error at least makes sense.

Anyways,  `hdfs dfs -put /test/students.text /test/` is one way to upload your file, assuming the `hdfs:///test` folder already exists. Otherwise,  `hdfs dfs -put /test/students.text /test` **renames your file** to `/test` on HDFS

Note: You can create an EXTERNAL TABLE over an HDFS directory, you don't need to use the LOAD DATA command.